Checking authorization status of AVCaptureDevice or CLLocation Manager gives runtime warnings in iOS 18
I have the following code in my ObservableObject class and recently XCode started giving purple coloured runtime issues with it (probably in iOS 18):
 Issue 1: Performing I/O on the main thread can cause slow launches.  

 Issue 2: Interprocess communication on the main thread can cause non-deterministic delays.

Here is the code:
@Published var cameraAuthorization:AVAuthorizationStatus
@Published var micAuthorization:AVAuthorizationStatus
@Published var photoLibAuthorization:PHAuthorizationStatus
@Published var locationAuthorization:CLAuthorizationStatus

var locationManager:CLLocationManager

override init() {

    // Issue 1 (Performing I/O on the main thread can cause slow launches.)
    
    cameraAuthorization = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) 


    micAuthorization = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.audio)
    photoLibAuthorization = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: .addOnly)

 //Issue 1: Performing I/O on the main thread can cause slow launches.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    locationAuthorization = locationManager.authorizationStatus
    
    super.init()
    
  //Issue 2: Interprocess communication on the main thread can cause non-deterministic delays.
    locationManager.delegate = self
}

I wonder how checking authorisation status can give these issues? What is the fix here?

There is so much being excluded but if I had to guess you are using MainActor on that class. MainActor is for UI only not everything else.

The class is initialised from AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions so it is main thread implicitly. But there is no documentation that says AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus can not be checked from main thread.

You are doing this on init of the app delegate? Apple says in multiple places not to ask for permissions when the app is starting, as for permission when the permission is needed. The app delegate is the wrong place for all of this.

Then where should one do it? Because I need to launch appropriate view controller based on the permission.

Afterwards, launch the app and have an in-between screen. Handle it where you handle changes in permission. What happens if the user changes permissions while using the app?

I am NOT prompting for permissions at the app launch. I am JUST checking the permission status in the class which is instantiated on startup. The prompts are displayed later on and on the click of a button.

can you try to use async alternatives to get the permission statuses?

This is what the errors are telling you.

You say ObservableObject is ..The class is initialised from AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions..., that does not seem to be the appropriate place to initialise it.
It should be @StateObject ... and in a View, then you can pass that one model to other Views.
Can you show how you declare this class and how you pass it to where you get the warnings.
Have a look at this Apple link Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app using ObservableObject.

@workingdogsupportUkraine But is that what the issue is here? I think the issue says I am invoking AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus from main thread, but there is nothing in documentation that says this call is a blocking call.

your comment is valid and without a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code all I (we) can do is guess what the problem could be.
